# How does three phase full converter work?

Tags: power-electronics, three-phase

[image]

My question is for firing angle(alpha)=0,why is T1 triggered at 30?

Comment: Because you should draw a rectified voltage from six diode bridge. Then you will notice that diodes doesn't start conduct at \$\omega t=0\$, but they switch when one phase becomes more positive than other.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič can u please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sinusoidal wave is positive for 180 degrees.

The switched half-cycle is stepped on at 30 derees, and stepped down at 150 degrees to align withe she sinusoidal wave.

The positive half cycle is from 0 to 180 in the diagram below.

[image]

Here is some ascii art depicting the stepped approximation of a sine wave:

```
    ____________
___|            |______               ___
                       |_____________|
0  30          150    210           330 360
```

Comment: But for alpha=0 it should conduct from wt=0 right?

Comment: Yes, it will conduct in the interval \$ [ 0 ; {4 \pi / 6} ] \$ leading 30 degrees.

Comment: Try this first.  Draw the stepped three-phase inverter currents.  See how they commutate every 60 degrees.  Then add the sinusoidal wave one of these approximates.  See you in chat.